# Swift - Stretchy header not working anymore under iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I've made a stretchy header like down below.

[image]

It's an imageView behind my table view. That's my code for it.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 170)
    let height = min(max(y, 220), 400)
    backdropPictureImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: height)
}
```

Under iOS 12 it works perfectly but not anymore under iOS 13. What did changed?

Answer (score 1):

for iOS 13 this worked for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    backdropPictureImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pic"))
    backdropPictureImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backdropPictureImageView!, at: 0)
    self.view.frame = tableView.bounds
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 170)
    let height = min(max(y, 220), 400)
    backdropPictureImageView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work with collection view by customize UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
class StretchyHeaderLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

        override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

            let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)! as [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
            let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset

            if (contentOffset.y < 0) {
                let deltaY = abs(contentOffset.y)
                for attributes in layoutAttributes where  attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
                    var frame = attributes.frame
                        frame.size.height =  headerReferenceSize.height + deltaY
                        frame.origin.y = frame.minY - deltaY
                        attributes.frame = frame
                }
            }

            return layoutAttributes
        }

        override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

    }
```

Dont forget to change the layout of collectionView in ViewDidLoad

```
let layout =  StretchyHeaderLayout()
yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```